# WFP Databinding dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

To summarize before posting my XAML, this form is very simple for now. There is a ListBox, two buttons and a context menu for the ListBox.

If the right mouse button is clicked in the ListBox, and NO ELEMENT is selected, my context menu, performs the ADD operation, which right now is just simply popping up a message box.

When an element is selected, such as MODIFY, my bindings do not work.  So I am assuming, after much reading, that I have an inheritance problem somewhere.  I have tried using DataContext, RelativeSource, etc...and still no joy.

Here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="FracasReportSettings.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="402"
    Width="578"
    Title="FRACAS Ticket Value Modification"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="91*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="194*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock FontSize="36"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Text="{Binding PageTitle}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="266,27,10,9" Width="112" Grid.Column="1" />

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="311" Margin="40,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111">
        <Button Content="Detection Method" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                Command="{Binding MyBinding}"
                CommandParameter="DetectionMethod"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListBox 
        Name="AdminList"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
        Height="302"  Width="231" Margin="151,22,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SomeName}"
       >

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>                                 
                </Style.Triggers> 
            </Style>                
        </ListBox.Resources>

       **<-- THIS WORKS FINE -->
       <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add"                             
                          Command="{Binding RCContentMenu}">                        
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>**

        <--MY ERROR IS IN HERE-->
        **<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">                    
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Modify"                                           
                                Command="{Binding Path=ModifyElementCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>

                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>                        
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>**

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The ModifyElementCommand is sitting in a ViewModel named MainViewModel.

The error I receive from the output window is:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListBox', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type
>   'Object')

Which I know means that the dependency cannot be found.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: `ContextMenu`s don't live in the same tree as the other elements. So you have to use some workarounds, e.g. try: `<Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding ElementName=AdminList}" />` and `<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext}">`.

Comment: I guess I do not totally understand. When I add the <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding ElementName=AdminList}" />  My WPF complains about the property being set twice...could yo give a markup of the section of code you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment here is the XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Modify"                                           
                    Command="{Binding Path=ModifyElementCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>

                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding ElementName=AdminList}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```